# Java MongoDb : Dot Notation

Tags: java, mongodb

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "52568424036439f2c5107571"} , "start" : { "x:" : 71 , "y:" : 9} , "end" : { "x:" : 30 , "y:" : 84}}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "52568424036439f2c5107572"} , "start" : { "x:" : 28 , "y:" : 59} , "end" : { "x:" : 72 , "y:" : 64}}
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "52568424036439f2c5107573"} , "start" : { "x:" : 16 , "y:" : 71} , "end" : { "x:" : 18 , "y:" : 79}}
```

Need all docs say  where start.x > 40

Query tried mongoDb console :

```
db.lines.find({"start.x": {$gt:40} })
```

Java Driver:

```
DBObject query = QueryBuilder.start("start.x").greaterThan(50).get();
collection.find(query)
```

Both cases no error, no documents retrieved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You named your field `x:` not `x` so this should do the work:

```
db.lines.find({"start.x:": {$gt:40} })
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used Mongo with Java, but... have you tried using `QueryBuilder.get` instead of `QueryBuild.start`? That's the method used for find operations.

You can also use a more specific one for this case: `QueryBuild.greaterThan`